# PowerPivot: Count of Slicer's selected items

Tags: excel, powerpivot, slicers

In PowerPivot, how do I get the count of selected items in a slicer. I intend to use the count in a calculated column.

For example:
I have two unrelated tables; a calendar table showing months from 2014 until 2020, and a person table showing people data.

If I create a slicer based on distinct people and call it Slicer A, how do I return the count for items that are selected.

[Slicer A]
Person 1
Person 2
Person 3
Person 4
Person 5

If I selected Person 1, Person 3, and Person 5, the total count would be 3; which I will use in a calculated column on my calendar table where 3 would appear for every month in the table.

I have looked everywhere, and have tried in vain multiple suggestions/solutions. However I continually return the overall total instead of a count of selected items.

Answer (score 0):

A clunky workaround I guess would be to make a seperate PivotTable with just the field of interest visible as a RowField, connect it to that Slicer, and point a COUNT or COUNNTA formula at the column it lives in.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but the formula needs to be within the data model and not on the worksheet. :)